# How to place the VLC output window in MFC Rich Edit Control Window in VC++?

Tags: visual-c++

I am using libvlc using vc++. I am trying to place the VLC output window in MFC Rich Edit Control Window.

`libvlc_media_player_set_xwindow (my_player,Id_Preview_Window);`
where  **Id_Preview_Window** is the Id of this window

Please help !!

Comment: question is unclear and dont have correct direction. It will be very helpful if you clear the question in better way.

Comment: I am using libvlc in MFC  vc++. I am trying to place the VLC output window in MFC Rich Edit MFC Window. Below is the command that I am using to fit the VLc output window inside the MFc window. but it is not working

'libvlc_media_player_set_xwindow (my_player,Id_Preview_Window);'where Id_Preview_Window is the Id of this window

Comment: add few code arround libvlc_media_player_set_xwindow (my_player,Id_Preview_Window);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of the term WindowID confused me for a little while there. I think for Win32 you would need to use libvlc_media_player_set_hwnd. The function you are using is intended for XWindows.

Comment: Now its working I  used :

libvlc_media_player_set_hwnd (my_player,Id_Preview_Window)